# StreamBuilder not correctly refreshing on new value

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

Probably it's my fault or a dumb error but this is what is happening to me:

*authController.dart:*

```
class AuthController {
BehaviorSubject _hometownController = BehaviorSubject();
Observable get hometown => _hometownController.stream;
void updateHometown(String hometown) {
    _hometownController.add(hometown);
    print(_hometownController.value); <- This always prints the expected value: "Hello!"`
}
}
```

*Login_screen.dart:*

```
class Login2 extends StatelessWidget {
  AuthController authController = new AuthController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: Center(
              child:
                  //Hometown:
                  StreamBuilder(
                    stream: authController.hometown,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.map),
                        title: Text("Hometown:"),
                        subtitle: snap.hasData ? Text(snap.data) : Text("Not set"),
                        onTap: () {
                          authController.updateHometown("Hello!");
                        },
                      );
                    }
                  ),
  ))));}}
```

And everything goes well.
But if I add an asynchronous function with async and await before authController.updateHometown:

*Login_screen.dart:*

```
                            onTap: () async {
                              var x = await something(); <- This always successfully completes
                              authController.updateHometown("Hello!");
                            },
```

The stream never receives the new value and the StreamBuilder never rebuilds!

*But if I use a statefulWidget class:*

```
class Login2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => Login2State();
}

class Login2State extends State<Login2> {
  AuthController authController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    authController = new AuthController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: Center(
              child:
                  //Hometown:
                  StreamBuilder(
                    stream: authController.hometown,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.map),
                        title: Text("Hometown:"),
                        subtitle: snap.hasData ? Text(snap.data) : Text("Not set"),
                        onTap: () async {
                          var x = await something();
                          authController.updateHometown("Hello!");
                        },
                      );
     }),))));}}
```

Everything goes well, even if I never call setState
Why is this happening?

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question something to take not of:
Creating your AuthController in the StatelessWidget will create a new AuthController every time the parent Widget rebuilds this Widget.

Comment: @ZeRj Yeah I know, but thesee examples are only attempts and are indicative for the scenario I am trying to test. They should not be taken as a good code example. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`Framework.dart`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart) :

A `StatelessWidget` builds itself depending on data that has two conditions:

1. can be read synchronously when the widget is
   built. And :
2. might change during the lifetime of the widget.

That's why when you make `Login2` as `StatelessWidget`, and then change the data in `authController` synchronously it is immediately reflected because it satisfies both conditions. But when you use an `async` function inside `onTap()` you break the first one.

And why `StatefulWidget` works with `async` function is because its `build` function only needs a data change to trigger `setState()` implicitly irrespective of whether this info is available synchronously or asynchronously.